# SetInterval/ClearInterval loop not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been answered before, but none of the other answers seemed to quite solve my problem. I have a timer function that, on invocation, should use setInterval to run every second for 5 seconds and then stop. This works once, but clearInterval doesn't seem to be working, since the second half of the countdown loop keeps running. I feel like this is a scope error, but I've tried moving setInterval and clearInterval outside the function with no luck. Here's my code - this function is called on a button click:

```
var startGame = function(){
  var count = 5;

  var countdownTimer = function(){
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  };

  var countdown = function(){
    if (count > 0){
      console.log('inside counter loop');
      count--;
      $('.timer').text('0:' + count);
    } else {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        console.log('inside endGame loop');
        //endgame(); //This should run once when the timer reaches 0.
     }
  };

    countdownTimer();

};
```

Right now, the loop will run correctly once, and then console.log 'inside endGame loop' every second without resetting. I want the loop to run once, stop, and then wait to be restarted until the on click handler calls the function again.

Answer (score 1):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns the interval id you need to store it and use that with [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

```
var startGame = function() {
    var count = 5;
    var intervalID ;
    var countdownTimer = function() {
        //Store the intervalID 
        intervalID = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    };
    var countdown = function() {
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log('inside counter loop');
            count--;
            $('.timer').text('0:' + count);
        } else {
            if (intervalID) {
                //Pass currect pointer
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }
    };
    countdownTimer();
};
```

Comment: Awesome, that solved it, thank you! I thought I tried this already, but I must have missed something last time. Thanks!